# Akka receive not matching case classes

Tags: scala, akka

I have a scala class that extends Actor and here are snippets from my code. All I'm doing is to try and get the receive to match the case object I'm sending.
Here is the case object:

```
private case object Msg
```

The logs from setMessage method below get printed, but the case class following it doesn't get matched. I get no logs or error messages corresponding to the `receive` .

```
def setMessage(msg: Message) = {
    log.info("In setMessage: received message with ID {}", msg.id)
    self ! Msg
}

override def receive = {
  case Msg =>
    log.info("Received msg")
  case default @ _ => log.info("Unhandled message: {}", default.getClass.getSimpleName)
}
```

What can be the possible reasons? How can I debug this?

Comment: Can you show some more code? The current part seems insufficient to understand what is going on.

Comment: Where is the case object defined? The inner object matching works bit unexpectedly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578165/scala-akka-pattern-matching-for-object-in-trait-issue?rq=1

Comment: Where `setMessage` define, how you call it?

Comment: can you show the whole code?